# Alternative to useStyles (makeStyles) - MUI v5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Many system components are styled using this pattern.

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    formControl: {
        color:props=>props.color || 'black',
        margin: '17px 8px 8px 8px',
        '& .MuiFormLabel-root': {
            top:'-19px !important',
        },
    },
}));

const FieldText=()=>{
    const classes = useStyles()

    return (
        <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
           <input type="text" />
        </FormControl>
    )
}

export {FieldText}
```

With Material-UI v4 → v5 update, you should use [themeProvider](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/migration-v4/#themeprovider-setup).

[image]

What would be the best way to keep the same style structure? And this can perform the same internal component selection operations like these "& .muiFormLabel" and "props=>props.color"

Answer (score 1):

You should probably go with `styled`:

```js
import { alpha, styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

const SuccessSlider = styled(Slider)<SliderProps>(({ theme }) => ({
  width: 300,
  color: theme.palette.success.main,
  '& .MuiSlider-thumb': {
    '&:hover, &.Mui-focusVisible': {
      boxShadow: `0px 0px 0px 8px ${alpha(theme.palette.success.main, 0.16)}`,
    },
    '&.Mui-active': {
      boxShadow: `0px 0px 0px 14px ${alpha(theme.palette.success.main, 0.16)}`,
    },
  },
}));

export default function StyledCustomization() {
  return <SuccessSlider defaultValue={30} />;
}
```

You can see this same example [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/#2-reusable-component). (Although the above example does not show the option, it is also possible to use props).

You can check more [here](https://mui.com/system/styled/).